# How to add all documents to an ArrayList in mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

How to add my all documents to `ArrayList`?

I'm using below code:

```
public void printAllDocuments(DBCollection collection)
{
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find();

    while (cursor.hasNext()) 
    {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  List<BasicDBObject> getAllDocuments(DBCollection collection)
{
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
    List<BasicDBObject> yourList = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

    while (cursor.hasNext()) 
    {
        yourList.add((BasicDBObject) cursor.next());         
    }
  return yourList;
}
```

Comment: `List<DBObject>` is fine and then you wouldn't need the extraneous cast in the while loop.

Comment: yep i agreed,but i preferred BasicDBObject instead of DBObject,beacuse future we don't need to cast while getting the value.

Comment: how to give date as input using java.Means I had one Company class and testCompany class(testCompany class had main method) i'm passing parameter date through testCompany class.don't no the format of date.help me

Comment: use date object of java only ,mongo-java driver auto convert to mongoDb format you no need to worry about it

Comment: i had used same Date object only.....how to give input from my main method class.

Comment: i want to hard code date from my tester class(main method),eg.11/07/2013. i'm giving this format, but i'm getting error..

Comment: CompanyBO c=new CompanyBO();
  c.setId(4);
  c.setCompanyName("Wipro");
  c.setCompanyAddress("Bangalore"); 
  c.setFinancialEndDate(null);
  c.setFinancialEndDate(null);
  c.setOsAnalysis("0");
  c.setActivityCenters("1");
  c.setPasswordCheck("0"); in above code i want to set financialStartDate and financialEndDate.....above code is my main method code.i'm updating date from main method to my class.

Comment: my document has been structred:

Comment: my document has been structred:
    "_id" : 1,
    "key" : 1,
    "Company_Address" : "Bangalore",
    "Company_Name" : "company",
    "Features" : {
        "OS_Analysis" : false,
        "Activity_Centers" : false,
        "passwordCheck" : false
    },and i want to perform update my document.means i want update only Feature("OS_Analysis" "Activity_Centers""passwordCheck"  )(using java), i'm tried,

Comment: but document stucture will changed.      
{   
 "Activity_Centers" : false,
    "Company_Address" : "Bangalore",
    "Company_Name" : "manju",
    "Features" : {
        "OS_Analysis" : false,
        "Activity_Centers" : false,
        "passwordCheck" : false
    },
    "Fianancial_End_Date" : null,
    "Fianancial_Start_Date" : null,
    "OS_Analysis" : false,
    "PasswordCheck" : false,
    "_id" : 1,
    "key" : 1
}like this, i'm not getting this plz help me how to update embedded documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toArray()` method gives you an `List` (you can cast to `ArrayList`).

Here is the code (based on what you already have, see the comment):

```
public static List<BasicDBObject> printAllDocuments(DBCollection collection) throws UnknownHostException {
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("CompanyAccounts");
        return collection.find().toArray();
    }
```

Make sure you are not calling it with a fairly large collection since the objects will be eagerly fetched if you use `toArray`.

From the Javadoc:

> Calling toArray or length on a DBCursor will irrevocably turn it into
>   an array. This means that, if the cursor was iterating over ten
>   million results (which it was lazily fetching from the database),
>   suddenly there will be a ten-million element array in memory. Before
>   converting to an array, make sure that there are a reasonable number
>   of results using skip() and limit().

Comment: How to call above method and print data.and getting fallowing errors java.util.NoSuchElementException: no more
 at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result.next(DBApiLayer.java:384)
 at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$Result.next(DBApiLayer.java:346)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor._next(DBCursor.java:421)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor.next(DBCursor.java:494)
 at com.calcify.accounts.company.Company.getAllDocuments(Company.java:255)
 at com.calcify.accounts.company.TestCompany.main(TestCompany.java:19), how to fix these.

Comment: @user3756637 can you post the exact code you are using? It seems you are calling `next()` on a cursor.

Comment: public  List<BasicDBObject> getAllDocuments(DBCollection collection) throws UnknownHostException
 {
  Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("CompanyAccounts");

    
     DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
     List<BasicDBObject> yourList = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

     while (cursor.hasNext()) 
     {
         yourList.add((BasicDBObject) cursor.next());         
     }
   return yourList;
 }

Comment: @user3756637 what is the version of your mongodb?

Comment: mongo shell version 2.4.10

Comment: @user3756637 I tested with the driver of 2.11.1 and mongo 2.4.10 and it is working on my machine. Which driver do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest Java driver you can do something like this.

```
ArrayList<Document> docummnetList = new MongoClient().getDatabase("database_name")
.getCollection("collection_name")
.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```